# Office 2013 can't open office 2010 protected file,vice versa

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, compatibility, microsoft-office-2010, microsoft-office-2013

I couldn't achieve to produce an interchangeable protected file between Excel 2013 and Excel 2010.

Excel 2010 can't open 2013s protected one and 2013 can't open 2010s protected one.

I think their protection algorithms are different and I don't know how to set up these algorithm while saving or opening the files.

If I try to save my XLSX  as Office 2007's XLS it says XLSX is more secure . This makes me annoyed about previous versions' security.

Am I the single one encountering this problem ?

Comment: In Office 2013 when you click on File -> Info -> Check for Issues -> Check Compatibility. What do you get ? In the Options -> Trust Center -> Trust Center Settings -> Protected View what is selected ? And in File Block Settings ? Have you installed the Compatibility Pack ?